# Bearings question confusion

Tags: trigonometry

At 12.00pm , a ship was spotted at a point P , 30 km due north of an island , L . The ship was sailing on a bearing of 120 degree at 32km/h . How far was the ship from the island at 12.30pm ?

My work is below

[image]

Distance travelled after 30mins =,$ 32 X .05 = 16km $

Angle LPH = 180 - 120 = 60 .

After here I got stuck on how to find the distance ? Can I get help , thanks in advance !

Answer (score 1):

You are given that $|LP| = 30~\text{km}$.  You computed that $|PH| = 16~\text{km}$ and that $\angle LPH = 60^\circ$.

[image: bearings_diagram]

You wish to find $|LH|$.  By the [Law of Cosines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_cosines),
$$|LH|^2 = |LP|^2 + |PH|^2 - 2|LP|~|PH|\cos(\angle LPH)$$